# looking for name of manga with noble girl, possibly named Mary

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

From what recall the Main Character (MC) was reincarnated as Mary the daughter of a noble family and has a strong body. She has a maid called Tutte, I think, and she becomes friends with a magician noble girl, a martial arts noble girl, and a martial arts noble boy, and the prince. Things happen and she gets called saintess/ silver or white knight. She gets friendly with a princess from the demon land and the prince's mother. She also rescues a holy beast and the younger sibling of that holy beast. I think that in the last chapter I read, she was visiting a vampire territory because the prince was turned into a girl because of an artifact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[Douyara Watashi no Karada wa Kanzen Muteki no you desu ne](https://isekai.fandom.com/wiki/Douyara_Watashi_no_Karada_wa_Kanzen_Muteki_no_you_desu_ne)* (AKA *It Seems like My Body Is Completely Invincible*).

> The world where Mary was reincarnated was called the Kingdom of Aldia, a fantasy world where monsters and spirits lived with swords and magic. Mary is born in a fantasy world but tries to live without being unreasonable, but it is a sign that her body was completely invincible by lifting heavy luggage lightly and unintentionally cutting the handle of the cup. Appears from an early age.
>
> **Mary, who lost control of her power, began to wear clothes with the help of Tutte.** As she is the daughter of the Marquis, she is always in the spotlight and it doesn't come true.
>
> [image]